# Don't number chapters

Tags: lyx, tex, markup

I am working on a school project, and I do not want to use chapters, and I want sections to be "the most important" style.

Right now, sections are numbered n.m, where n is the chapter (0), and m is the section, I want it to display just m, or make chapter format like sections normally do. (ie. don't output "chapter", do not create a new page)

I am using the report class.

Edit: On second thought, I do want hard page breaks after each section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change to the Article class, you can choose "Section" as the top-most level, and "Subsection*" as the next level, to avoid numbering on that sub-level.

Hard page breaks would probably have to entered manually from the Insert->Formatting menu.

Or Chris' solution probably ultimately works too...